# CakePHP Query results caching

Tags: php, caching, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Recently I moved `CakePHP 3.2` project to web hosting (`CentOS`, `php 7.0/5.6` tried both, `OpCache` enabled), and found that query results caching doesn't work.

I use default file cache engine for navigation menu.

```
$mt = TableRegistry::get('MenuItems');
$menu = $mt->find('active')
           ->select([
                      "MenuItems.id",'Nodes.id','title', 'header', 'route', 'link',
                      'parent_id' => 'Nodes.parent_id' ])
           ->orderAsc('Nodes.num')
           ->cache("sitemenu_MenuItems", 'long')
           ->hydrate(false)
           ->toArray();
```

I had not problems with this code on local `OpenServer`, `IIS7` and `IIS8` servers and other `Linux` server.

so, what is happening:

When I run script for the first time, cake fetches the data from DB and writes cache to `/src/tmp/cache/long/cake_sitemenu__menu_items`. File has serialized contents as usual.
But when I refresh the page I see empty result.

There is nothing in error or debug log.

I've tried to lowercase cache key, but with no luck.

Any ideas ?

---

I've added test code to check basic caching itself:

```
    public function qwe(){
            $data = ['key' => 'value'];
            //Cache::write('test', $data, 'long');
            $result = Cache::read('test', 'long');
            $result[] = 'xxx';
            $this->setJsonResponse($result);
    }
```

and this code returns correct result.

---

so far I found that there is some problem `read()` method of `Cake\Cache\Egine\FileEngine` class. line 223:

```
$data = unserialize((string)$data);
```

`$data` has the same value before call on hosting and local machine. and then `unserialize` returns `ResultSet` object with empty `items` field;

---

it seems there is something with `SplFixedArray` and `unserialize`

hah, nice: [PHP 7.0.15 and PHP 7.1.0 ResultSet Caching #10111](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10111)

Comment: the same with IIS8.5 & PHP 7.1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, during dubugging I found that problem was caused by `SplFixedArray` which `ResultSet` uses and `unserialize()`.

After that I found [this topic: PHP 7.0.15 and PHP 7.1.0 ResultSet Caching #10111](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10111).

In my case I tried to use PHP `7.0.24`, `7.1.5`, `5.6.30` and `5.5.38`. And 5.5 worked well.

This problem was fixed during that topic discussion, so I copied `ResultSet::serialize` and `unserialize` methods from `CakePHP 3.5`. The trick was to serialize data as usual array, not `SplFixedArray`.

`\Cake\ORM\ResultSet`

```
313:     public function serialize()
314:     {
315:         if (!$this->_useBuffering) {
316:             $msg = 'You cannot serialize an un-buffered ResultSet. Use Query::bufferResults() to get a buffered ResultSet.';
317:             throw new Exception($msg);
318:         }
319: 
320:         while ($this->valid()) {
321:             $this->next();
322:         }
323: 
324:         if ($this->_results instanceof SplFixedArray) {
325:             return serialize($this->_results->toArray());
326:         }
327: 
328:         return serialize($this->_results);
329:     }
330: 

339:     public function unserialize($serialized)
340:     {
341:         $results = (array)(unserialize($serialized) ?: []);
342:         $this->_results = SplFixedArray::fromArray($results);
343:         $this->_useBuffering = true;
344:         $this->_count = $this->_results->count();
345:     }
```